# Semantic UI React Modal : Portal.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to implement [semantic-ui-react modal](https://react.semantic-ui.com) in my react dashboard application, I've created a ModalManager component which would be used alongside Redux to manage the state of  Modal_Open and Modal_Close.

The Redux part works great, however, during render I see issue only with "Semantic-UI-React-Modal component. Below is the error message

```
invariant.js?7313:42 Uncaught Error: Portal.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
    at invariant (invariant.js?7313:42)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:830)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:361)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?c56c:45)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:370)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js?063f:257)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js?c56c:45)
    at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js?c86a:121)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js?e1f8:206)
```

Below is the code for Modal manager, it is able to render other components ( some test charts ) on  `return <span>{renderedComponent}</span>;`
I suspect the problem is when the rendered component is Semantic-Ui-React-Modal other components work just fine.

I am using React 16.4.1

> Modal Manager Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Modal } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { closeModal } from "../../Redux/actions/modalActions";

export class ModalManager extends Component {
  render() {
    const { modalConfiguration } = this.props;

    const defaultProps = {
      defaultOpen: true,
      closeIcon: true,
      onClose: this.props.closeModal
    };

    let renderedComponent;

    if (modalConfiguration) {
      const { modalProps = {} } = modalConfiguration;
      renderedComponent = <Modal {...Object.assign({}, modalProps, defaultProps)} />;
    }

    return <span>{renderedComponent}</span>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { modalConfiguration: state.modals };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { closeModal })(ModalManager);
```

> Home Page

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {

  state = {
    expanded : false,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    axios.get(API)
    .then(result => this.setState({
      T_Bugs: result.data.map(x => Number(x.code_bugs)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),     
      isLoading: false
    }))
    .catch(error => this.setState({
      error,
      isLoading: false
    }))

  }




  render() {



   if (this.state.expanded) {
     this.setState( () => {
        return {
          expanded : false
        };
     });
   }



    return (
        <div>
          <Main expanded={this.props.expandedState}>
          <h1>Welcome to Stemplot</h1>

           <Card.Group stackable={true} itemsPerRow={8}>
           <StatCard loading={this.state.isLoading} image={this.state.isLoading ? "/images/spinner.gif":"/images/Duplicate.svg"} description=" XXX" title="Duplicate Lines" value={nFormat(this.state.T_Duplicate_Lines)}/>
            </Card.Group>
           <br/>
 <ModalManager />

          </Main>



        </div>
    )
  }

}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        expandedState: state.sidebarReducer.expanded
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (HomePage);
```

Comment: What are you rendering inside the modal?

Comment: Your modal implementation doesn't look anything like what the docs are recommending. where is `trigger` or `children`? https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-modal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not rendering any children inside the `Modal` nor you are passing the required props as per the [docs](http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-modal)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { openModal: false }

  toggleModal = () => this.setState(state => ({ openModal: !state.openModal }));

  render() {
    const { openModal } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Toggle Modal</button>
        <Modal open={openModal} closeIcon onClose={this.toggleModal}>
          <Header icon='browser' content="I' m a header" />
          <Modal.Content>
            <h3>I'm a content</h3>
          </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Running example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/w6o0mm24qw)

Comment: Still the same issue :(
   renderedComponent = <Modal open={true}> <Header icon='browser' content='Im a header' /><Modal.Content><h3>I'm a content</h3></Modal.Content></Modal>

Comment: i've added a running example so you can test for yourself and see what are the differences from your code

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue when I upgraded Semantic UI React from 0.7x to 0.82. My issue ended up being that after the upgrade, I was still using React version 15.x on my project. When I updated to React 16.x, the modal issue went away. So check your `package.json` for what version of react you're using. If it's 15.x or lower, try updating it. If you're using yarn, then `yarn install react` should do the trick. Just be aware that this may open up other compatibility issues in your project you may need to solve.